# How to customize the built in menu in wordpress?

Tags: menus

This is my first post and question in wordpress stackexchange. I'm a newbie in wordpress. I'm having a problem with the menu. I want to place a custom icons in the menu and add some text just like the screenshot below. I wonder if someone could help me make that possible.

[image]

Best regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin and this plugin will allow you to add a menu icon for menus.
`https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-icons`

You can also use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu to create a custom menu and for displaying menu in your theme you can use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Hi Aftab thanks for your reply. Ahmm currently I'm using divi theme. My problem is that the default menu is still displaying the links. and I want those links to be removed and add like that one in my screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Then you can create a child theme and override the header.php file and change the code to display only the icons and link from menu. Icons can be added in menu by adding the plugin I have shared.  Thanks